# jquery autocomplete search not sorting for multiple key value pairs

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, search, autocomplete

I am using jquery ui autocomplete search to search for subjects in one of my project . But I am having one problem . replica of my search i have implemented in  [this js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnkitaPalekar/no3taLbv/1/)

In first search I am using single json array object without any key value pairs and that is why i get correct result in my autocomplete search see image below and

**code for array consisting only of subjects**

```
 var responseArray =["Electrical Machines II-2009","6- Sigma Management -2012", "Advanced Computer Architecture-2012","Advanced Controlled  drives -2011","Advanced Mechanics of Solids-2010","Analog & Digital Circuits-2009","Analog Communication-2012", "Antenna & Wave Propagation-2010","Applied Mathematics I-2012", "Applied Operational Research-2012",    "Applied Sciences - II (Physics & Chemistry)-2012","Applied Thermodynamics-2008","Artificial Intelligence -2010","Automata Language and Computation-2009"];  
 $("#search-correct").autocomplete({
            source:   responseArray,
            minLength: 1,
            search :  function(event,ui){   
            $( "#search-bar" ).on( "autocompletesearch", function( event,ui) {} );
            } 
              });
```

[image: correct search]

Now on select of applied mathematics I wanted to open a new link that's why I did   call where in I am binding all subjects with different key value pairs like link name and sub code but after binding I am getting wrong results on search .
You can see  image below and

**code for search with key value pairs**

```
 var responseArray1=[{"fullName":" Electrical Machines II-2009","paperLink":"http://domain.in/examLibrary/EE4/2009/DEC/ee4-2009-dec-ee4.4.pdf","sub_code":"EE4-4","yr":"2009"},{"fullName":"6- Sigma Management -2012","paperLink":"http://domain.in/examLibrary/ME7/2012/MAY/me7-2012-may-me7.4f.pdf\n","sub_code":"ME7-4F","yr":"2012"},{"fullName":"Analog & Digital Circuits-2009","paperLink":"http://domain.in/examLibrary/IT3/2009/DEC/it3-2009-dec-it3.3.pdf","sub_code":"IT3-3","yr":"2009"},{"fullName":"Analog Communication-2012","paperLink":"http://domain.in/examLibrary/ETC5/2012/MAY/etc5-2012-may-etc5.3.pdf\n","sub_code":"ETC5-3","yr":"2012"},{"fullName":"Antenna & Wave Propagation-2010","paperLink":"http://domain.in/examLibrary/ETC6/2010/MAY/etc6-2010-may-etc6.4.pdf\n","sub_code":"ETC6-4","yr":"2010"},{"fullName":"Applied Operational Research-2010","paperLink":"http://domain.in/examLibrary/ME7/2010/DEC/me7-2010-dec-me7.5f.pdf","sub_code":"ME7-5F","yr":"2010"},{"fullName":"Artificial Intelligence -2013","paperLink":"http://domain.in/examLibrary/CO6/2013/MAY/co6-2013-may-co6.3.pdf\n","sub_code":"CO6-3","yr":"2013"},{"fullName":"Automata Language and Computation-2013","paperLink":"http://domain.in/examLibrary/CO5/2013/MAY/co5-2013-may-co5.2.pdf\n","sub_code":"CO5-2","yr":"2013"},{"fullName":"Biomedical Instrumentation-2012","paperLink":"http://domain.in/examLibrary/EE8/2012/MAY/ee8-2012-may-ee8.4d.pdf\n","sub_code":"EE8-8D","yr":"2012"}]
 $("#search-bar").autocomplete({ 
          source: function (request, response) {  
                  response($.map(responseArray, function(item) {
                  return {
                            label: item.fullName,
                            value: item.fullName,
                            linkValue : item.paperLink,
                            sub_code  : item.sub_code,
                            yr: item.yr
                          }
              }));
            },
            minLength: 1,
            search :  function(event,ui){
              $( "#search-bar" ).on( "autocompletesearch", function( event,ui) {} );
            } });
```

[image: wrong search]

where in i am searching for applied mathematics but I am getting results for electrical engineering 
can anyone help me with this ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dropping the function wrapper from the source, so you're just passing in the mapped dataset, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/no3taLbv/2/

```
          source: $.map(responseArray1, function(item)                 {
                  return {
                            label: item.fullName,
                            value: item.fullName,
                            linkValue : item.paperLink,
                            sub_code  : item.sub_code,
                            yr: item.yr
                          }

            }),
```

Comment: thanks alot :) I was really tensed because this was not working and i could not find where I was wrong .